# Injected Transient service still tracks entities in ChangeTracker in DbContext

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

When I Insert an entity, and directly after, try to update the same entity, as follow:

```
var insertedTransferId = await _transferDs.Create_Async(transferObject);

//update transfer key
if (insertedTransferId > 0)
{
    transferObject.TransferKey = $"{transferObject.TransferKey}00{insertedTransferId}";
    return await _transferDs.Update_Async(transferObject, true);
}
```

_transferDS Create_Async(TransferModel model)

```
public async Task<int> Create_Async(TransferModel model)
        {
            try
            {
                var entity = _mapper.Map<Transfer>(model);

                this._repo.Create<Transfer>(entity);
                this._repo.Context.Entry(entity).Reference(nameof(entity.TransferMeta)).IsModified = false;
                var success = await _repo.SaveAsync() > 0 ? true : false;

                if (success)
                    await this.UpdateTransferByTransferId(entity.TransferId);

                return success ? entity.TransferId : 0;
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

_repo.Create(entity)

```
public virtual void Create<TEntity>(TEntity entity)
    where TEntity : class
{
    Context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
}
```

I run into the following issue:

> The instance of entity type 'Transfer' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value is already being tracked

After the initial insert, the `EntityState` is `Added`.  When I update the entity, it complains that the entity is already being tracked.

I thought, with the help of .Net Core DI(), I could inject my context, services etc with the `Lifetime` scope of `Transient`, meaning, whenever I request, for instance, my context, a new instance will be provided, and the `ChangeTracker` will be clean.  Not the case.

Below, you can see, I am setting my context's lifetime, as well as service:

```
//Database context and repository
services.AddDbContext<IMyContext, MyContext>(builder =>
{
    builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString: Configuration.GetConnectionString("myConnection"), sqlServerOptionsAction:  null);
    builder.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
    //builder.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
    builder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true); 
}, ServiceLifetime.Transient);

services.AddTransient<IRepo, Repo>();
```

Am I missing something, or not understanding something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#service-lifetimes):

> Transient
>
> Transient lifetime services (AddTransient) are created each time they're requested from the service container. This lifetime works best for lightweight, stateless services.

So `Create_Async` and `Update_Async` method calls are invoked on the same instance of `_transferDs` which will have the same instance of your db context, cause `_transferDs` needed to resolve `MyContext` only once.

To check it you can try to inject `MyContext` into `Repo` twice and call different ones on `Create` and `Update`(don't do it in real/production code though).

**UPD**

*How would I force a new instance everytime?*

I don't think you should, you can check that entity is already tracked or use [`Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.find?view=efcore-3.1), but if you insist - you can register "factory" (in addition to ordinary registration) and resolve it:

```
services.AddTransient<Func<IRepo>>(s => () => s.GetRequiredService<IRepo>());
```

Inject `Func<IRepo> repoFactory` into your classes and use it instead of `_repo`:

```
var repo = _repoFactory();
repo.Create<Transfer>(entity);  
repo.Context.Entry(entity).Reference(nameof(entity.TransferMeta)).IsModified = false;
var success = await repo.SaveAsync() > 0 ? true : false;
```

Comment: _transferDS is also added with the lifetime scope of 'Transient'.  So would it not create a new instance of _transferDS, anytime I would try to access _transferDS?

Comment: No, it is injected in your code only once (i assume the code you provided is in one method)

Comment: How would I force a new instance everytime?

Comment: Brilliant answer. Thank you :-)
I tried to clear the ChangeTracker, but it gives the error of entity relationship beign severed.

Comment: @monstertjie_za was glad to help!